# DecimalFormat Spaghetti

Tags: java, decimalformat

First time using the DecimalFormat classes...

I need to store 4 decimals precision for my value.
Let me show you what I have done so far.

```
public class Paper 
{
    public String name, color, type,finish,grain;
    public double width,height,gsm, lbs,ppi;
    public DecimalFormat df;


    public Paper() 
    {
        String pattern = "#0.0000";
        df = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

    }

    public void setWidthAndHeight(String width, String height) 
    {

       //I've censured what I tried so far.    
      ///I need to ensure that the passed width has 4 decimals and that it is stored that way. 

       this.width = //ENTER answer here! :)

    }
```

Thank you for your time, and patience.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can use BigDecimal to manage your decimals.

```
BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("100.12345");
n = n.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
n = n.stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(n.toPlainString());
```

Using scale will round your number to 4 decimal precision. Remove any zeros using  stripTrailingZeros and use toPlainString to get your number later for printing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: For *four* decimals of precision?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad.  Java doesn't actually have a `decimal` type.